# Singly Link List Copy Constructor

Tags: c++

Not sure why the nodes are still not deep copying? The head and size are deep copying perfectly fine.

Seems both NewNode->Data and NewNode->Next aren't deep copying. Not sure if NewNode is still pointing to That->Data and That->Next.

Do I need to pass in the actual values when the node are created?

Thanks in advance for any replies. Much appreciated.

The list passing in (SLList& that).

Node is the structure. Node doesn't use a tail. Only a next and size in my case.

```
Node* That = that.Head;

//If not null then deep copy.
if (That != nullptr)
{
    Head = that.Head;
    Size = that.Size;

    //Interate through the list until the end nullptr
    while (That != nullptr)
    {
        Node* NewNode = new Node;

        NewNode->Data = That->Data;
        NewNode->Next = That->Next;
        That = That->Next;
    }
}

//Set the head to null if list passed in is empty.
else if (That == nullptr)
{
    Head = nullptr;
    Size = 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it so that since you create the NewNode pointer inside of your while loop, the pointer is deleted after you leave it?

Comment: You might want to see my corrected code.

Comment: someone is serially downvoting every answer simply because they don't like the question? I don't like the code style either but that is not a reason not to answer the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem 1:

```
Head = that.Head;
```

Whups! Two lists point at the same head. This isn't going to end well. In fact, it utterly defeats the point of a deep copy of a linked list.

Solution:

Don't do this.

Problem 2:

```
while (That != nullptr)
{
    Node* NewNode = new Node;

    NewNode->Data = That->Data;
    NewNode->Next = That->Next;
    That = That->Next;
}
```

`NewNode` is never saved anywhere outside the loop. That makes this loop a memory leak generator that loses all of the copies.

Solution:

Make the node copies as you currently do, but store the first copied node in `Head`.

Problem 3:

```
NewNode->Next = That->Next;
```

The copy points to a node on the list being copied.

Solution:

`NewNode->Next` needs to point to the next node on its list. Unfortunately this node doesn't exist yet. So you'll have to make the new node first or use recursion.

Comment: Ooo, okay I see what you saying, the Node* NewNode is falling out of scope. I need to store it either in the Head so it doesn't fall out of scope after the while loop is finished. Thus leaks memory once the pointer is lost.

Answer (score -1):

1. You should create a new list and its next pointers should be pointed to its nodes only not the original list's nodes.
2. Never name your variable same as members of your structs and classes. 
   It creates confusion.

Below is the corrected code.

```
Node* That = that.Head;

List new_list;

//If not null then deep copy.
if (That != nullptr)
{
    new_list.Head=new Node;
    new_list.Size = that.Size;
    Node * head = new_list.Head;

    //Interate through the list until the end nullptr
    do{

        head->Data = That->Data;
        That = That->Next;
        if(That!=nullptr){
            auto tmp = new Node;
            head->Next = tmp;
            head = tmp;
        }
    }while(That!=nullptr);

//Set the head to null if list passed in is empty.
else if (That == nullptr)
{
    new_list.Head = nullptr;
    new_list.Size = 0;
}

return new_list;
```

Comment: A couple of things I dislike in your solution: calling a node "head" when it isn't (it is at first but then it becomes the tail) and doing a while(1) when you can use a while with a terminating condition or even a for loop here.

Comment: @CashCow Its not me who named the variables, the questioner did.

Comment: @CashCow, you suggest a better condition. I choose that method, I did not want to create one extra node.

Answer (score -1):

Much that I would have to say about the style of the raw "new" calls in your code and having to clean up later, the obvious bug I see is that you forget to "chain" to your "NewNode" and instead are chaining to That->Next which is in the list you are copying.

As your list is singly linked, you need to keep a pointer to the current "tail" and then as you create a new node, you put (using your style)

```
Tail->Next = NewNode;
NewNode->Data = That->Data;
Tail = NewNode;
```

What you are actually doing is creating a node where you clone the data but your linked list is not using your new nodes but still using the old ones.

As this is C++ where you have a constructor, NewNode should create automatically with nullptr as its "Next" value so if we do not loop further, we can assume that is set.

In reality, we can also pass in the data we need to the constructor, thus:

```
template< typename DataType >
class SLNode
{
public:
      DataType Data;
      SLNode< DataType > * Next;

      SLNode() : Next( nullptr )
      {
      }

      ~SLNode(); // exercise for you to implement

      explicit SLNode( const DataType& data )
             : Data( data ), Next( nullptr )
      {
      }
 };
```

I have made everything public but you may wish to make the data members private and have use getters and setters.

Anyway, now you can do the following in your loop....

```
 while( That )
 {
     Tail->Next = new SLNode< DataType >( That->Data );
     Tail = Tail->Next;
     That = That->Next;
 }
```

Your "Head" in your new list is also incorrect as that is pointing to a node from the old list. Still, we now know how to create that

```
 Head = new SLNode< DataType >( that->Data );
 Tail = Head;
```

We need to keep Head as well as Tail as Tail will move as we recurse, Head will stay in the same and is the head of our list.

Comment: I'm starting to think someone doesn't want this question answered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, definitely a good read. Sorry if I seem like an idiot. Fairly new to C++ about a few months in. I will Definitely have a look at it tomorrow, I'm going to go to bed it's 3:50 am lol. Rep ++. Also, we didn't have to implement a tail variable to the lab.

Comment: The tail variable is only in the loop. You don't need it in the class. You need to keep track of the tail of the input list (which you called That) and also of the one you are writing.